# Python link downloader slow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

Is there anyway to improve the speed of this script by using lxml or mechanizer and cutting out beautiful soup all togther?

python:

```
import lxml.html as html
import urllib
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os, sys
print ("downloading and parsing bibles...")
root = html.parse(open('all.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
  url = link.get('href')
  name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
  dirname = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('.')[-1]
  f = urllib.urlopen(url)
  s = f.read()
  if (os.path.isdir(dirname) == 0): 
    os.mkdir(dirname)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
  articleTag = soup.html.body.article
  converted = str(articleTag)
  full_path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
  open(full_path, 'w').write(converted)
  print(name)
print("downloads complete!")
```

all.html

```
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas</a>
```

Comment: Is not the download what takes the time?

Comment: that takes most of the time, but couldnt I use lxml instead of beautifulsoup and improve speeds?

Comment: Those are for parsing. If the download takes the most of the time, parser is irrelevant.

Comment: Could I use mechanize for a faster download?

Comment: If those are many files, you can try to download them in separate threads. That may help.

Comment: I do not think that mechanize will help either. I do not think that is the purpose of the package. But I am not very familiar with it so I guess based on the description. You should start with measuring what really takes time in your script. Optimizing something which is not slow is waste of your time.

Comment: alright thanks for all the info :) can you make a response post so I can mark it as completed?

Comment: Alright than. If that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with measuring what really takes time in your script. Optimizing something which is not slow is waste of your time.

It is probably the download, not the parsing. In that case switching the parser will not help. To speedup downloading of many files using threads (one for each download) **may** help as another download can start before the first is completed.